# How to simplify shapefiles without losing attributes?

Tags: shapefile, attribute-table, mapshaper

I want to simplify a huge shapefiles using [mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org/). However whenever I simplify the shapefile I loose a lot of data attributes. how can we simplify the shape files while retaining at least some of the data attributes?

Comment: Simplification must not have any effect on attributes. If is does it is a bug in a program. But perhaps there is something odd in your environment like mixed versions of program libraries that Mapshaper is using. I suggest to contact the developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run it in the browser, you do seem to lose most of the attributes. Installing it locally using [npm](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper#installation) and running it from a terminal fixes this problem. You don't even need to specify the `-fields` option.